# HMM trans and estm matrix initialization

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

How do I know what to set for the initial values of trans and estm matrix in hidden markov model for training? Should I set them randomly?

Comment: Are you asking about unsupervised learning of HMMs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using depmixS4 package in R. No need to give initial probabilities. Model itself will take initial default transition probabilities, state participation probabilities, emission values.

```
    model <- depmix(response = diff ~ 1, data = t, nstates = states, transition = ~ (calls)+(samples)+ (fto) + (copay) +(spk_prgm))      
  summary(model)

  fm <- fit(model, verbose = F)
```

if you see summary model you can look at all the initial default probabilities( parameters), And after fitting you can see model parameters.